# why javascript-ajax submitting form multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing single page app. If i type something on form and click the submit button then it sends one request. Second time if i type something and click it sends two requests. Third time it sends three requests and so on. Why is this? Did i do any mistake in javascript code?

here is my html

```js
function reply_mail(idi) {
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#reply-view').style.display = 'block';
  fetch(`/emails/${idi}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(email => {
      // Print email
      var strp = `${email.subject}`;
      var ini = 'Re: '
      document.querySelector('#reply-recipients').value = `${email.sender}`;
      if (strp.slice(0, 4) == 'Re: ') {
        document.querySelector('#reply-subject').value = `${strp}`;
      } else {
        document.querySelector('#reply-subject').value = ini.concat("", strp);
      }
      var output = `On ${email.timestamp}  ${email.sender} wrote:|
          ${email.body} |
          `;
      // ... do something else with email ...
      document.querySelector('#reply-body').value = output;
      // ... do something else with email ...
      console.log(email);

    });
  document.querySelector('#reply-submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    rec = document.querySelector('#reply-recipients').value;
    sub = document.querySelector('#reply-subject').value;
    bod = document.querySelector('#reply-body').value;
    fetch('/emails', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          recipients: rec,
          subject: sub,
          body: bod
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        // Print result
        if ('error' in result) {
          console.log(result);
          document.querySelector('#reply-error').style.display = 'block';
          document.querySelector('#reply-error-i').innerHTML = `<p>${result['error']}</p>`;
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          document.querySelector('#reply-error').style.display = 'none';
          load_mailbox('sent');
        }
      });
  })
}
```

````html
```
<div id="reply-view">
  <h3>New Email</h3>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="reply-error">
    <div id="reply-error-i">
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="reply-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="soham@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      To: <input id="reply-recipients" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="reply-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="reply-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="reply-submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
</div>
````

Comment: is that JS code the entirety of your script, or is there more? In particular is it inside a function, and if so how is that function used? From what you describe it sounds suspiciously like it's getting run multiple times, and not just on page load.

Comment: updated the code. i am doing single page app.

Comment: Where do you call `reply_mail()`?

Comment: If you call `reply_mail()` multiple times, you'll add duplicate event listeners.

Comment: My guess is you call `reply_mail()` from `load_mailbox()`, which you call after the fetch is successful. So you add an additional event listener each time.

Comment: i call reply_mail() from load_mail() function which is from load_mailbox() function. So what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: just remove everything in the `document.querySelector(...).addEventListener` from the function and have it run only once when the page first loads.

Comment: then how can I use onclick property?